# Stuck on syntax pushing an object built into an array

Tags: java

Attempting to push this object that I'm building my while loop into a list array. I can't exactly figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can some one please explain first, what the best syntax is and the best way to pull out this information to push it to a list array. so later I can access the list array by getting the information out of it.

```
    public void getTableConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
      SQLException {
    List<Car>cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    Car car = new Car();


    try {
        Table table = new Table();
        table.getTableConnection();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carrentalsystem";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "javatest";
        String query = "select * from cardetails";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, 
          password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            car.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            car.setYear(rs.getString("Year"));
            car.setMake(rs.getString("Make"));
            car.setModel(rs.getString("Model"));
            car.setColor(rs.getString("Color"));
            car.setAvailable(rs.getString("Availability"));
            String renting;
            car.add()
         }


        return cars;
      }catch(Exception e) {

      }finally{

      }

   }
```

Comment: you might wan to check line `car.add()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change that line to cars.add(car)

Answer (score 0):

At the first place you didn't add car to cars.You can't change the value of the returned ArrayList (cars) in the finally block if it is already returned. So don't return from try.